# How to log all fingerprints in sshd, even if the connection was unsuccessful?

Tags: ssh, authentication, public-key

I understand that by adjusting the `LogLevel` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I can log the fingerprints when authentication is successful, but what I would like to do is to see a fingerprint of a key that was in fact **unsuccessful**.

The practical problem is clueless clients who connect to the server using the wrong key and if I could see the fingerprint when authentication fails that would help a lot.

The OS is Ubuntu Precise Pangolin, OpenSSH server from the package `openssh-server (1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1)`.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, I believe if you set the loglevel to say "verbose" the information printed in auth.log will only show a failed publickey for a user from an IP address and the port number.  I don't believe there is a loglevel which will allow you to see the publickey that was unsuccessful